# UnicodeDecodeError: cp932 codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 81

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm trying to open an '.obj' file using 2 python scripts, but when I try compiling the project, it throws me the next error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 81: illegal multibyte sequence
```

My code looks like this:

```
CarString = 'volks.obj'
global car
global objects

obj = test3.object()    
car = obj.load_obj(CarString)

objects.append(glGenLists(1))
```

Class object:

```
class object():
    def __init__(self, obj = None):
        if obj:
            self.load_obj(obj)
            #self.displaylist = self.crear_dl()

    def load_obj(self, file):
        with open(file, 'r') as obj:
            data = obj.read()
```

The

```
data = obj.read()
```

part is what throws me this error. I'm new to Python so I can use some help to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `volks.obj` file is likely binary data, not text.  The default data type in the `open` command is text, so you need to specify binary.

Try:

```
def load_obj(self, file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as obj:
        data = obj.read()
```

If the file does indeed contain text and is not the default encoding of your system (usually `utf-8`, but looking at your error message it's probably `cp932`), you must specify the text encoding in the `open` call.

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding=<encoding_type>) as obj:
```